# HTML CSS Unicode "entity" different line height than standard font?

Tags: html, unicode, entities, css

I have this code:

```html
<button class='arrow month'>&#x25C2;</button>
<button name='nv' value='2011' class='month selected'>2011</button>
<button class='arrow month'>&#x25B8;</button>
```

...to output this:

[image]

Everything's groovy, except the unicode "entities" are making the line fatter!

Why is this happening and is there a fix?

To illustrate further, here's the same HTML, with an entity included:

```html
<button name='nv' value='2011' class='month selected'>2011&#x25B8;</button>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the CSS for this? The entities don't add any extra height when I try this on a clean CSS reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will wholly depend on what fonts you've got. If the browser's default font doesn't have a glyph for character U+25C2, it'll try to fall back to another font that does contain that character. That fallback font might have a different line-height.

If you want a fixed-height button, ask for it by specifying a fixed `height` style.

Comment: Apparently this is indeed the problem - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/geometric_shapes/fontsupport.htm.  And while we're following links, http://www.hackvalue.nl/en/article/103/finding_the_right_utf-8_symbol fills in a few blanks too.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I add `line-height: 16px;` and solved.